# Highlight option in stacked barchart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I've developed a stacked column chart. In that if I click one stacked column I've to get all the details(all stacked columns) of that column.

Is that possible? I tried it but I didn't get a solution.

Comment: We could help more if you gave the code you tried. But saying it "din [sic] get a solution." is not useful. What errors? What was wrong?

Comment: your question is not simple i don't even understand it

Comment: Can you clarify your question showing us what have you tried ? What's the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo to start with:
[Column With Drilldown](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown)

You can manipulate this to get what you need. Their demo gallery is a great place to start when thinking of ideas to use.